# Нужна помощь в формировании рандомного списка чисел на Python с применением random и json

Tags: python, json, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте! У меня есть маленький скрипт на `Python`, который принимает список чисел и должен внести их в `json` файл.

```
import random
import json

filename = 'dict.json'
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
new_numbers =[]


def random_number(nums):
    number_of_attempts = int(input('Введите количество паролей, которые должна сформировать программа: '))
    i = 0
    score = 0
    while i <= number_of_attempts:
        i += 1
        score += 1
        print('Попытка номер ' + str(score))
        random.shuffle(nums)
        new_numbers.append(nums)
        if nums == new_numbers:
            random.shuffle(nums)
        else:
            pass

    with open(filename, 'r+') as f_obj:
        json.dump(new_numbers, f_obj)
    f_obj.close()

random_number(numbers)
```

Данный скрипт формирует список с 10 цифрами в рандомном порядке(но мне нужно 11 цифр, если в переменной `nums` добавить 11 цифру, тогда будет две постоянно повторящиеся, есть какие либо еще варианты?)

И на выходе в `json` файле я получу примерно такой результат `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`, можно ли как-то убрать запятые и `[]` с помощью нового скрипта на питоне?

P.S По моей задумке, программа должна подбирать разные вариации паролей из моего `json` файла. Но т.к там имеются запятые и `[]`, идет неккоректный подбор :(

Comment: вы хотите получить заданное число (`number_of_attempts`) случайных чисел с k=11 десятичными цифрами? К примеру: такой json файл хотите [`with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file: json.dump([random.randrange(10**(k-1), 10**k)  for _ in range(number_of_attempts)], file)`](https://ideone.com/BHPSky)?

Comment: да, спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Это не ответ, это комментарий, уточняющий вопрос. Так как принятый ответ внизу другую задачу решает, то так и не ясно какой ожидаемый вывод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]` - это не список, это человекочитаемое представление списка. Если будете список в строку через `str()` или `repr()`, то такой вид и получите. Можно конечно из этой строки потом удалить внешние скобки и запятые, но это неправильный путь.

А правильный путь такой. Чтобы просто собрать все цифры в одну строку, нужно пройтись по списку, каждую цифру превратить в строку, а потом все их собрать в одну строку при помощи `join`:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
s = ''.join(str(d) for d in x)
```

В переменной s получим строку вида `'1234567890'`